# Postgres How to execute SQL statement from command line

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm using Ubuntu i want to execute : `sudo -i -u postgres  testodb < db.sql` . this doent working.
any help
Thanks

Comment: Is `testodb` your database name?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an adequate description.